# getting records for yesterday day starting till ending PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Currently my application is running over 2 dbs one is `snapshotDB` one is `evercamDB`. In `snapshotDB` we are saving records now it want to retrieve them , currently am using this query

```
select camera_id,count(*) as snapshot_count 
from snapshots 
where snapshot_id in (select snapshot_id 
                      from snapshots 
                      where created_at = 'now'::date - 1) 
group by camera_id
```

what i want is to get records from `snapshots` such as am considering today is `2016-01-21` and i want to get all records from yesterday. `'2016-01-20 00:00:00'` to `'2016-01-20 23:59:59'`. i really dont know how to bind time with `'now'::date - 1` in such format as i have written.

And i want to place this date and time in `(select snapshot_id from snapshots where created_at = 'now'::date - 1)` so that i can get records as i want.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast `created_at` as a `date` - that will remove the time.

`now()` also contains a time, so you need to use `current_date`

And finally your `IN (..)` is not needed, you can apply that condition directly in the `where` clause:

```
select camera_id, count(*) as snapshot_count 
from snapshots 
where created_at::date = current_date - 1
group by camera_id;
```

---

Note that the above will **not** use an index on `created_at`. If the performance is not acceptable and the condition *would* benefit from using an index, you can use something like this:

```
select camera_id, count(*) as snapshot_count 
from snapshots 
where created_at >= date_trunc('day', current_timestamp) - interval '1' day
  and create_at < date_trunc('day', current_timestamp)
group by camera_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT camera_id,
       count(*) AS snapshot_count 
FROM snapshots 
WHERE created_at >= current_timestamp - interval '1 day' 
  AND create_at < current_date - 1   
GROUP BY camera_id;
```